# Can you append data to an existing Avro data file?

Tags: avro

It seems like there isn't any way to append data to an existing Avro serialized file.  I'd like to have multiple processes writing to a single avro file, but it looks like each time I open it, I start over from scratch.  I don't want to read in all the data and then write it back out again.

Using the ruby example code I have tried "ab" and "ab+" as various settings, but no joy.

```
file = File.open('data.avr', 'wb')
schema = Avro::Schema.parse(SCHEMA)
writer = Avro::IO::DatumWriter.new(schema)
dw = Avro::DataFile::Writer.new(file, writer, schema)
dw << {"username" => "john", "age" => 25, "verified" => true}
dw << {"username" => "ryan", "age" => 23, "verified" => false}
dw.close
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't pass the schema to append to the file

Answer (score 4):

I did figure out how to do it in Java using the appendTo method:

```
DatumWriter writer = new ReflectDatumWriter(Record.class);
DataFileWriter file = new DataFileWriter(writer);
file.setMeta("version", 1);
file.setMeta("creator", "ThinkBigAnalytics");
file.setCodec(CodecFactory.deflateCodec(5));
//file.create(schema, new File("/tmp/records"));
file.appendTo(new File("/tmp/records"));
```

However, I'd love to do it from Ruby.