# Can I append Avro serialized data to an existing Azure blob?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-blob-storage, avro

I am asking if I *can*, but I would also like to know if I *should*.

Here's my scenario: 
I am receiving Avro serialized messages in small batches. I want to store them for later analysis using a Hive table with the Avro SerDe. I'm running in Azure, and I am storing the messages in a blob.
I am trying to avoid having lots of small blobs (because I believe this will have a negative impact on Hive). If I have the Avro header already written to the blob, I believe that can append Avro data blocks with `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync()`. (As long, as I know the sync marker.)

However, I've examined two .NET libraries and that don't seem to support my approach. (I have to write the entire Avro container file at once).

- http://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Avro/
- http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro/

**Am I taking the correct approach?**
**Am I missing something in the libraries?**

My question is similiar (but different) to this one:
[Can you append data to an existing Avro data file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806689/can-you-append-data-to-an-existing-avro-data-file)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is that I was trying to do the wrong thing.

First, we decided that Avro is not the appropriate format for the on-the-wire serialization. Primarily, because Avro expects the schema definition to be present in every Avro file. This adds a lot of weight to what is trasmitted. You *could* still use Avro, but that's not what it's designed for. (It is designed for big files on HDFS.)

Secondly, the existing libraries (for .NET) only support appending to Avro files via a stream. This does not map well to Azure block blobs (you don't want to open a block blob as a stream).

Thirdly, even if these first two could be bypassed, all of the items in a single Avro file are expected to share the same schema. We had a set of heterogenous items flowing in that we wanted to buffer, batch, and write to blob. Trying to segregate the items by type/schema as we were writing them to blob added lots of complication. In the end, we opted to use JSON.

Comment: Here's the code that resulted from our exploration: https://github.com/mspnp/data-pipeline

Comment: Heterogeneous items could be easily expressed in avro via union types

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do.

First of all, you have to use CloudAppendBlob:

```
CloudAppendBlob appBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(
            string.Format("{0}{1}", date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), ".log"));


appBlob.AppendText(
                string.Format(
                "{0} | Error: Something went wrong and we had to write to the log!!!\r\n",
                dateLogEntry.ToString("o")));
```

Second step is to tell to avro lib not to write header on append and share the same sync marker between appends:

```
var avroSerializer = AvroSerializer.Create<Object>();
        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var w = AvroContainer.CreateWriter<Object>(buffer, Codec.Deflate))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Init Sample Data Set...");
                var headerField = w.GetType().GetField("header", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                var header = headerField.GetValue(w);
                var marker = header.GetType().GetField("syncMarker", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                marker.SetValue(header, new byte[16]);
                using (var writer = new SequentialWriter<Object>(w, 24))
                {
                    // Serialize the data to stream by using the sequential writer
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        writer.Write(new Object());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Append Sample Data Set...");

            //Prepare the stream for deserializing the data
            using (var w = AvroContainer.CreateWriter<Object>(buffer, Codec.Deflate))
            {
                var isHeaderWritten = w.GetType().GetField("isHeaderWritten", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                isHeaderWritten.SetValue(w, true);
                var headerField = w.GetType().GetField("header", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                var header = headerField.GetValue(w);
                var marker = header.GetType().GetField("syncMarker", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                marker.SetValue(header, new byte[16]);

                using (var writer = new SequentialWriter<Object>(w, 24))
                {
                    // Serialize the data to stream by using the sequential writer
                    for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        writer.Write(new Object());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Deserializing Sample Data Set...");
        }
```