# appending to existing avro file oython

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I'm exploring the avro file format and am currently struggling to append data. I seem to overwrite in each run. I found an existing thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806689/can-you-append-data-to-an-existing-avro-data-file), saying I should not pass in a schema in order to "append" to existing file without overwriting. Even my lint gives this clue: `If the schema is not present, presume we're appending.`. However, If I try to declare `DataFileWriter` as `DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), None)` then the code wont run.

Simply put, how do I append values to an existing avro files without writing over existing content.

```
schema = avro.schema.parse(open("user.avsc", "rb").read()
writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)

print("start appending")
writer.append({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
writer.append({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 12, "favorite_color": "blue"})
writer.close()
print("write successful!")

# Read data from an avro file
with open('users.avro', 'rb') as f:
    reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
    users = [user for user in reader]
    reader.close()

print(f'Schema {schema}')
print(f'Users:\n {users}')
```

Comment: It might be the way the file is opened. You currently have `wb` but the `w` will always overwrite the file. Does `ab` work?

Comment: Don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with the standard avro library, but if you use `fastavro` it can be done. See the example below:

```py
from fastavro import parse_schema, writer, reader

schema = {
 "namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}

parsed_schema = parse_schema(schema)

records = [
    {"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256},
    {"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 12, "favorite_color": "blue"},
]

# Write initial 2 records
with open("users.avro", "wb") as fp:
    writer(fp, schema, records)

# Append third record
with open("users.avro", "a+b") as fp:
    writer(fp, schema, [{"name": "Chris", "favorite_number": 1}])

# Read all records
with open("users.avro", "rb") as fp:
    for record in reader(fp):
        print(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to skip the schema is correct, but only once you have the Avro file set up with the correct schema.

In your code, what you have incorrectly, was to put `wb` instead of `ab` in the file open mode.

Putting `None` or no argument at all in DataFileWriter should not matter and the code should run.

This reproducible code initializes the file in the correct schema. It does not matter if it is `ab` or `wb` mode, just write to an empty file with a schema and close it.

```
writer = DataFileWriter(open("reproducible.avro", "ab+"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.close()
```

Now to write the actual records in the append mode (so no re-reading the file!), you can skip the `schema` while in the `ab` mode:

```
for i in range(3):

    writer = DataFileWriter(open("reproducible.avro", "ab+"), DatumWriter())
    writer.append(db_entry)
    writer.close()
```

Finally, read the entire file:

```
reader = DataFileReader(open("reproducible.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for data in reader:
    print(data)
reader.close()
```

Works for me on Windows, with Python 3.9.13 and avro library `1.11.1`.

For full reproducible example, please begin with:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
import json

schema = {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "recordName",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}

schema = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(schema))

db_entry = {
    "id": "random_id"
}
```